# How can I modify my IP address on my localhost in MAMP?

Tags: wordpress, ip, mamp, akismet

Developing a plugin for WordPress locally I'm wanting to implement Akismet in form validation but I'm required an IP address with the submission and when I run:

```
function check_ip_address() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) :
        $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else :
        $ip_address = "undefined";
    endif;
    return $ip_address;
}
echo check_ip_address();
```

I get back a `::1`.  When I researched to resolve this I didn't find a solid answer from:

- [Ask Different tag MAMP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mamp)
- [How do I rename MAMP web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369897/how-do-i-rename-mamp-web-server)

When researching how to resolve `::1` I found [Should a MAMP return ::1 as IP on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699454/should-a-mamp-return-1-as-ip-on-localhost) that suggests a `sudo` of:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

So I go to `MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` and try to modify line 48 from `Listen 8888` to `Listen 127.0.0.1` and I get an error and Apache will not restart.  How can I modify my MAMP IP so I can get a proper IP from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `::1` because that's the IPv6 loopback address, equivalent of `127.0.0.1`, and the remote address is yourself as MAMP is running locally, the remote browser is on the same machine.

`REMOTE_ADDR` represents the IP the request came from. In most scenarios this is the same as the IP the browsers machine has on the open-internet, but here MAMP is running Apache natively so it's `127.0.0.1` or `::1`. If you were using a docker container or a Virtual machine, it would be a private IP on a range specified when configuring your containers/VMs.

So to retrieve the IP you're expecting, you'll need to use an external service, or, for the sake of debugging, pass Akismet a hardcoded IP, but I suspect it's asking for the IP of whomever is commenting.